# How to write automake files to recursive build subdirectories?

Tags: linux, autotools, autoconf, automake

My working directory as following tree shows:

```
./  
|--HelloWorld/  
|--|--main.cpp  
|--|--Dog/   
|--|--|--Dog.h  
|--|--|--Dog.cpp    
|--Pet/  
|--|--Pet.h  
|--|--Pet.cpp  
|--build/
```

The `main.cpp` includes `dog.h` and `pet.h`. Dog is an inherited class of Pet, so `Dog.h` also includes `Pet.h`. I know this is a wired way to organize the codes, but I'm just curious about **how to create makefile.am files for each subdirectories so that autotool can build the project in the build directory.**

Note that I would like to have some additional features:

1. Is that possible we build the hello.exe at `build` directory instead of `build/HelloWorld/` directory? To do this, do I have to put the `bin_PROGRAMS` at the `./Makefile.am`
2. I do not want to build Pet as librarys, I'm wondering whether there is a way I can just tell automake to find source codes in different locations.
3. I know that using non-recursive makefile would be easier. But I just want to learn how to create recursive makefiles for multiple directories.

What I have tried is:

**configure.ac**

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([Hello], [1.0], [qub@oregonstate.edu])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign subdir-objects])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([HelloWorld/main.cpp])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])

# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_PROG_CC
#AC_PROG_CPP

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile
                 HelloWorld/Makefile
                 Pet/Makefile
                 HelloWorld/Dog/Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

**Makefile.am**

```
SUBDIRS = HelloWorld Pet
```

**HelloWorld/Makefile.am**

```
AM_CPPFLAGS=-I$(srcdir)/../Pet -I$(srcdir)/Dog 
SUBDIRS = Dog
bin_PROGRAMS=hello 
hello_SOURCES = main.cpp
```

**Pet/Makefile.am**

```
hello_SOURCES = Pet.h Pet.cpp
```

**HelloWorld/Dog/Makefile.am**

```
AM_CPPFLAGS=-I$(srcdir)/../../Pet

hello_SOURCES = Dog.h Dog.cpp
```

I just started learning automake things, and I know these codes do not work at all.

Could anyone help me to fix them? Thank you.

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58352194/how-to-build-in-a-separate-directory-with-autotool/58355042

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you're interested in

> **how to create makefile.am files for each subdirectories so that autotool can build the project in the build directory**

, but this is not an appropriate goal, as this example itself demonstrates.  It is rarely useful or appropriate to have a `Makefile.am` that does not define any targets to be built.  You have stipulated that you don't want to build Pet as a library, so what target would a `Makefile.am` in its directory define?  Similar applies to `Dog` if you want to avoid building it as a library.  There is little or no point to using recursive `make` in this situation.

I do note, however, that Automake has the concept of a "convenience library", which is an intermediate target that is never itself installed, but contains object code that can be linked into an executable or a larger library.  I will demonstrate this later, as it's the most sensible way to set up the makefile-per-directory structure you are asking for in this particular case.

Additionally, with respect to directing the output to a specific directory in the source tree: this can be done, but it is probably a waste of effort.  The Autotools already provide a convenient method for out-of-source building that more easily accomplishes the goal of separating the build results from the source in the event that the person building the project wishes to do that.

**NEVERTHELESS**, [the basics of recursive builds with the Autotools](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Subdirectories.html) are pretty simple.  There are two main things to do:

- each `Makefile.am` that wants to express a recursion into one or more subdirectories does so by listing the relative paths to each of those subdirectories in the variable `SUBDIRS`.
- the project `configure.ac` must designate of the `Makefile`s to be built via its `AC_CONFIG_FILES` macro.

That's all you need to do to set up the recursion generally, and the details of how to set up specific targets and options are project-specific.

> 1. Is that possible we build the hello.exe at `build` directory instead of `build/HelloWorld/` directory? To do this, do I have to put
>      the `bin_PROGRAMS` at the `./Makefile.am`

Yes, you can specify building into `build/hello` rather than `build/HelloWorld/hello`.    You might not strictly ***have*** to put the corresponding `bin_PROGRAMS` into the top-level `Makefile.am`, but you definitely *should* put it there or in a `build/Makefile.am` file.  I urge you to avoid trying to have any makefile build targets outside the tree rooted at the directory where that particular makefile resides.

> 2. I do not want to build Pet as librarys, I'm wondering whether there is a way I can just tell automake to find source codes in
>      different locations.

You can absolutely specify source files in a different directory from the `Makefile.am`.  Just provide the appropriate path, relative to the makefile's directory.  This makes more sense for sources in the same tree as the makefile, but using sources located elsewhere is not as much of an issue as trying to build targets elsewhere.

> 3. I know that using non-recursive makefile would be easier. But I just want to learn how to create recursive makefiles for multiple
>      directories.

Non-recursive makefiles are not necessarily easier than recursive ones, but they are generally *better*, because they express the whole target / prerequisite tree as a unit instead of chopping it up into pieces.  `make` can make better build decisions when it has all the information at once.

> I just started learning automake things, and I know these codes do not
>   work at all.

My answer to [your related question](http://I%20just%20started%20learning%20automake%20things,%20and%20I%20know%20these%20codes%20do%20not%20work%20at%20all.%20Could%20anyone%20help%20me%20to%20fix%20them?) provides a recursive solution to a related problem.  It demonstrates one of the key principles that you seem to be missing: the variables specifying a target's sources and other build properties need to appear in the same `Makefile.am` file in which the target itself is defined.  Each `Makefile.am` corresponds to a separate makefile.  To a first approximation, data are not shared between makefiles, so all the information needed to build a given target needs to appear in the same one.

The other thing that seems to distinguish this question from your other is that you want (however wrongheadedly) to specify a particular output directory *in your makefile*. Do remember that wherever the built files initially go, it is a staging area -- it doesn't much matter, because they get put in their final destination by `make install`.  Even so, you can specify a target residing in a different directory by giving the correct relative path to it.  Of course, such a change to the target name needs to be reflected in [the names of the variables derived from the target name](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Canonicalization.html#Canonicalization).

Here, then, is a recursive Automake setup that should build your example project using one makefile per source directory:

---

**Makefile.am**

```
SUBDIRS = Pet HelloWorld

# Note: specifying output into a different directory
bin_PROGRAMS = build/hello

# Note the form of the following names:
build_hello_SOURCES = HelloWorld/main.cpp
build_hello_CPPFLAGS = -I$(srcdir)/Pet -I$(srcdir)/HelloWorld/Dog
# Note that library order matters
build_hello_LDADD = HelloWorld/Dog/libDog.a Pet/libPet.a
```

**Pet/Makefile.am**

```
noinst_LIBRARIES = libPet.a

libPet_a_SOURCES = \
    Pet.cpp        \
    Pet.h
```

**HelloWorld/Makefile.am**

```
SUBDIRS = Dog

# No own targets defined here, just the recursion into Dog.  This could have been
# skipped altogether, but I'm sticking to the letter of one Makefile.am per source
# directory.
```

**HelloWorld/Dog/Makefile.am**

```
noinst_LIBRARIES = libDog.a

libDog_a_SOURCES = \
  Dog.cpp          \
  Dog.h
libDog_a_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/Pet
```

---

Your `configure.ac` ought to work with that as-is.

Note this does not rely on `VPATH`; it builds *specifically* into the `build/` subdirectory of the build tree, including when you build directly in the source tree.

Comment: Thank you @john Bollinger for your detailed answer. I believe this would work, but each directory is build to a library. Just being curious, is there a way to let make file just compile the cpp file inside each subdirectory and output the .o files, then let the ./makefile.am to link them to the main function?

Comment: @Burton, if even never-installed convenience libraries are unsatisfactory to you, then the question as you have framed it has no answer.  The answer I've presented already explains why this is, but to recap: you're building only one target, and all the information about any given target needs to go into the same Makefile (.am).  The example you've presented as not appropiate for recursive `make`, and convenience libraries are the best available accommodation for forcing it into that paradigm.  They introduce additional targets for the wanted additional Makefiles to build.